# Does binding engine also call INotifyDataErrorInfo GetErrors() when ErrorsChanged event is not invoked by viewmodel?

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, data-binding, inotifydataerrorinfo

I've got a viewmodel that implements the `INotifyDataErrorInfo` interface.

When a property is updated and a validation error occurs, I call the `ErrorsChanged` event, the binding engine then knows it has to call the `GetErrors(string propertyName)` method on my viewmodel, and from there I return the `IEnumerable` of errors for the corresponding `propertyName`.
Nothing special.

But when I was debugging, it seems to be that the `GetErrors()` method is called when a viewmodel property changes (on invoking INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged of course). Even while my viewmodel didn't invoke `ErrorsChanged`.

Does the binding engine call `GetErrors()` on its own when a property change is notified? (And thus not only when my viewmodel explicitly invokes `ErrorsChanged`?)

I can't find it in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the binding engine call GetErrors() on its own when a property change is notified? (And thus not only when my viewmodel explicitly invokes ErrorsChanged?)

Yes. The `TransferValue` method, which eventually get called when you raise a `PropertyChanged` event for a UI bound source property, in the `BindingExpression` class calls `UpdateNotifyDataErrors` as you can see in the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Data/BindingExpression.cs,43c3ed4a53141207,references).